# When $x$ is given, what is $\mathrm{d}x$?

Tags: derivatives, infinitesimals

In the spherical coordinate, we know that $x = r\sin\theta\cos\phi$. Why does it imply that 
$$\mathrm{d}x = r\cos\theta\cos\phi \mathrm{d}\theta - r\sin \theta\sin \phi \mathrm{d} \phi?$$
It is first time I have faced this one. I tried to find some informations on Google, but I do not know what to search. Which rules do you use here?

Comment: What are the derivative of $\sin(teta)$ and $\cos(phi)$.

Comment: That formula is meaningless end and of itself; it, however, is usually understood to mean what to substitute in a change of variables.

Answer (score 2):

This is called the total derivative. If $f=f(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ then
$$df=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}dx_i.$$
You can take a look at the [Wikipedia entry: Total dervative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

If $A=f(u,v,w)$

then under some conditions
$$dA=\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}du+...$$

Answer (score 0):

To understand this, you must know that $x,r,\theta,\phi$ are (almost) smooth functions defined on the usual Euclidean space, and $dx,dr,d\theta,d\phi$ are the derivatives of these functions.

Derivatives abide by a few rules: 
Linearity: if $u,v$ are smooth and if $t$ is a scalar, then $d(u+tv)=du+t\cdot dv$.
Leibniz: if $u,v$ are smooth, then $d(uv)=u dv+vdu$. 
Chain rule: if $f$ is smooth and $u$ is a smooth function from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself, then $d(u \circ f)=u’\circ f df

As a consequence, constant functions’ derivatives vanish. So to get your formula, you just need to apply Leibniz’s rule and assume that in your context $r$ is a constant function.